Meaning of "distributional version" of a system
I am refering to this paper, page 11, equations (27)-(29).
The system
$$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon\partial_t f_1+v\cdot\nabla_x f_1&=-R_1+\varepsilon(\chi_1-\rho_2 f_1)\tag{27}\\
\varepsilon\partial_t f_2+v\cdot\nabla_x f_2&=-R_2+\varepsilon(\chi_2-\rho_1 f_2)\tag{28}
\end{align}
$$
is considered. Note that here $\rho_i(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f_i(x,v,t)\, dv$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi_i(v)\, dv=1$.
Afterwards, it is said that when considering the limit $\varepsilon\to 0$ in the distributional version of this system, one gets
$$
R_i^0=-\chi_i v\cdot\nabla_x\rho_i^0,\quad i=1,2\tag{29}.
$$
What is meant by the distributional version of (27) and (28)? How to get (29)?

If I let $\varepsilon\to 0$ in (27) and (28), I formally get
$$
R_i^0=-v\cdot\nabla_x f_i
$$
I do not see where in (29) the $\chi_i$ and the $\rho_i^0$ arise from.

Not really my field, but isn't "distributional" just referring to the probability distribution as opposed to the probability density?

I think it has more to do with considering the PDE system in the sense of distributions. But I cannot figure out here, how this results in (29)

If so, you should integrate on a function in the Schwartz space.

And thats exactly my point where I have problems: I think that $\chi_i$ is supposed to be a special choice for a Schwartz function. So I have to multiply both sides by $\chi_i$ and then integrate with respect to $v$, I guess.  But I do not get $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}R_i \chi_i, dv= R_i$ which seems to be used here.

No, my point is that $\chi_i$ should be considered distributions themselves. These represent the density of probability in velocity and could be centered at some specific value to grant their integral to be equal 1.

Do you mean that $\chi_i$ are distributional solutions of (27)-(28) when $\varepsilon\to 0$?

At the start of Theorem 9 of the paper, there is the condition
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f_i=\rho_i^0\chi_i.
$$
Now, consider both the equations in the same limit
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(R_i+v\cdot\nabla f_i)=R_i+\chi_iv\cdot\nabla\rho_i^0=0,
$$
from the aforementioned limit conditions in the statement of the theorem. The authors mean in the distributional sense because $\rho_i^0$ are indeed distributions.

Am I right that $f_i=\rho_i\chi_i$ is supposed to mean
$$
\langle f_i,\varphi\rangle = \langle\rho_i\chi_i,\varphi\rangle~\forall \varphi\in L_{\text{loc}}^2((0,\infty);L_i^2),
$$
where this inner product is the one defined for $L_i^2$ on page 10? In other words,
$$
\iint\frac{1}{\chi_i}f_i(x,v,t)\varphi(x), dv, dx = \iint\rho_i(x,t)\varphi(x), dv, dx
$$
so that
$$
f_i = \rho_i\chi_i
$$
in the sense of distributions (that is, the regular distributions generated by $f_i$ and by $\rho_i\chi_i$)?
Or in which sense is $\rho_i$ a distributional solution as claimed?

Yes, you are right.

So if I am correct, $\rho_i\chi_i$ is a distribution (i.e. generates a regular distribution) on a unweighted space and $\rho_i$ is a distribution on the weighted space $L_i^2$?

Some statement about this point is in the proof of theorem 9 in the paper. On the other hand, I have not studied this paper enough. Would you think the effort is worthwhile?
